# reload the route emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a profile route

```
 Remon.ProfileRoute=Ember.Route.extend({

    activate: function() {
    console.log("act");
  },

   model: function(params){
    return this.store.find("profile",params.profile_id);

 }
});
```

and here is my router.js

```
Remon.Router.map(function(){
 this.route("news");
  this.resource("profiles");
   this.resource("profile",{path:'profile/:profile_id'},function(){
 this.route("photos");
  });
 });
```

and my link-to helper

```
  {{#link-to "profile" 1}}another profile {{/link-to}}
```

when I visit a profile from profiles main page it work good and activate method also work but when I am on the profile page and tried to visit another profile url not changed but model data for the second profile are loaded
from profiles main page when I click on a profile

```
Attempting transition to profile.index ember.js?body=1:3462
Transition #33: profile: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #33: profile: profile: resolving provided model ember.js?body=1:3462
  Transition #33: profile: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #33: profile.index: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #33: profile.index: calling deserialize hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #33: profile.index: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #33: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition. ember.js?body=1:3462
  act            profile_route.js?body=1:3
  Transitioned into 'profile.index' ember.js?body=1:3462
  Transition #33: TRANSITION COMPLETE
```

when I click on another profile on the same profile page no transition to the new model occurred but the template changed to the new data but url keeps the previous one

```
 Transition #34: profile: profile: resolving provided model ember.js?body=1:3462
Transition #34: profile: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
Transition #34: profile.index: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
Transition #34: profile.index: calling deserialize hook ember.js?body=1:3462
 Transition #34: profile.index: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3462
  Transition #34: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing
```

in console it stopped at

```
   Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition.
```

and "Transitioned into 'profile' not appeared and activate method not triggered too

**update**

I think I found where is the error
I have multiple layouts

```
 Remon.MainLayoutView = Ember.View.extend({


didInsertElement  : function(){
    console.log("pr");
    this._super();

  this.$('#simple-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr-left',
      side: 'left',
      source: '#myside',
      renaming: false
  });
},
willAnimateIn : function () {

    this.$().css("opacity", 0);
},

animateIn : function (done) {
    this.$().fadeTo(500, 1, done);
},

animateOut : function (done) {
    this.$().fadeTo(500, 0, done);
},
layoutName: 'layouts/application' });

Remon.ProfileView=Remon.MainLayoutView.extend();
```

after I removed the animateout method ,it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs for [activiate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate):

> This hook is executed when the router enters the route. It is not executed when the model for the route changes.

Seems like [beforeModel](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) might be the best place to put that code, but I'm not sure what your intention is. What are you wanting to do?

That said, your URL should change when you change models within the `profile` page. What does your `link-to` look like there?

Here is an example project which has your router and properly changes the URL.

[Full screen app](http://jsbin.com/rezibisi/2) (to see the url changing)

[code on js bin](http://jsbin.com/rezibisi/2/edit)

### Update

I tried to get the library you referenced (Sidr) to work, but I'm unable to (in a reasonable amount of time). I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sidr'` in the console.

[Here is the code](http://jsbin.com/rezibisi/4/edit).

Comment: url not changed , in the profile route  I tried many things like 
{{#link-to 'profile' 1}} first profile {{/link-to}}
 and I tried to get the main profile as an object and I passed it to link to ,,,outside the route it work great ..but inside the profile route it breaks

Comment: simply I need when I click on another profile link in the profile route to reload every thing like when I click it from profiles route for example

Comment: @RemonAmin - I just added a code example which shows how the url will properly update. It is best to work with the framework instead of trying to force it to do something else.

Comment: I found the problem ,actually I am having 2 layouts I will update my code to let u see how I do it

Comment: Hi Remon, you need to link to your update if you want us to see it.

Comment: Also could you please explain these things (it'd help enormously): 
1. Exactly what steps you're doing and what happens
2. What you expect to happen when you do these steps
3. What is it doing instead and why is that different to your expectation.

(Ie ... "1. Type google.com and press enter in firefox. Microsoft's webpage loads. 2. I expect google's site to load 3. I should be on google's homepage, not microsoft's, because I'm trying to get to google's site.")

Comment: @RemonAmin - To add to what Julian said, I'd also recommend trying to replicate the issue in a JSBin so that we can try the code out for ourselves and iterate on it faster. Animation is (I believe) "half" supported in Ember right now. They are working to make better support in the future.

Comment: sidr is jquery plugin and it work great with me , the main problem was in animateout method